# React: Updating multiple object variables in array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to implement a voting system in my app where you can vote thumbs-up or thumbs-down for a selected movie. The ratings will be saved in a ratings array of objects that contain movie title, id, thumbs-up votes and thumbs-down votes. If a movie has no votes, the first vote will add the new object into the ratings array, and subsequent votes will update the thumbs-up votes and thumbs-down votes of the object. My current code works for the first thumbs-up vote and adds the new obj into the array, but does not update the vote count for subsequent votes. How can I update the votes in the movie object for both thumbs-up and thumbs-down votes? This involves incrementing the count depending on whether the thumbs-up or thumbs-down button is clicked. How can I handle this besides creating separate but similar functions for each button like I’ve already started to do? Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
const ThumbRating = ( {id, title} ) => {

const [thumbsUpCount, setthumbsUpCount] = useState(0);
const [thumbsDownCount, setthumbsDownCount] = useState(0);
const [ratings, setRatings] = useState([]);

const newUpVote = (id) => {
    if (thumbsUpCount === 0 && thumbsDownCount === 0) {
        setthumbsUpCount(thumbsUpCount + 1);
        const obj = {
            id: {id},
            title: {title},
            thumbsUpCount: thumbsUpCount +1,
            thumbsDownCount: thumbsDownCount
        }
        setRatings([obj])
    } else {
        setthumbsUpCount(thumbsUpCount +1)
        handleThumbsUp(id, thumbsUpCount +1)
    } 
}

const handleThumbsUp = (id, thumbsUpCount) => {
    setRatings(ratings.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id !== id) return obj
        return {...obj, thumbsUpCount: thumbsUpCount +1}
    }))
  }

return (
<div className="thumb-rating">
    <p>Would you recommend this movie?</p>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div >
        <button className="thumbs-up" onClick={() => newUpVote(id)}>
            <i className="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-4x" />
        </button>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div >
        <button className="thumbs-down" onClick={() => setthumbsDownCount(thumbsDownCount + 1)}>
            <i className="fa fa-thumbs-down fa-4x" />
        </button>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Yes: {thumbsUpCount} </h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>No: {thumbsDownCount} </h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is My solution:

The `handlerHandleCountDown` is working and the state is correcting updating.

Now you can try to handle the countDown based on the example.

Do not forget to pass `id` and `title` as props to your component.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const ThumbRating = ({ id, title }) => {
  const [thumbsUpCount, setthumbsUpCount] = useState(0)
  const [thumbsDownCount, setthumbsDownCount] = useState(0)
  const [ratings, setRatings] = useState([])

  const newUpVote = (id) => {
    if (thumbsUpCount === 0 && thumbsDownCount === 0) {
      setthumbsUpCount(thumbsUpCount + 1)
      const obj = {
        id, // id:id also works but id: {id} will not
        title,
        thumbsUpCount: thumbsUpCount + 1,
        thumbsDownCount: thumbsDownCount,
      }
      setRatings([obj])
    } else {
      setthumbsUpCount(thumbsUpCount + 1)
      handleThumbsUp(id)
    }
  }

  const handleThumbsUp = (id) => {
    // Is better to use the find method when you want to find a single element in an array

    const objectToBeUpdated = ratings.find((obj) => obj.id === id)

    objectToBeUpdated.thumbsUpCount += 1 // I assumed you will always update by one
    setRatings([objectToBeUpdated])
  }

  return (
    <div className='thumb-rating'>
      <p>Would you recommend this movie?</p>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div>
                <button className='thumbs-up' onClick={() => newUpVote(id)}>
                  <i className='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-4x' />
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>
                <button
                  className='thumbs-down'
                  onClick={() => setthumbsDownCount(thumbsDownCount + 1)}
                >
                  <i className='fa fa-thumbs-down fa-4x' />
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h2>Yes: {thumbsUpCount} </h2>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h2>No: {thumbsDownCount} </h2>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThumbRating
```